# Transient classes in CLOS

Tags: garbage-collection, lisp, common-lisp, clos

Is there any standard way to create a transient class in CLOS; that is, a class which can be GC'd after all its instances are dead?

In SBCL, I tried `(setf test (defclass #:foo () ()))`, i.e. using an uninterned symbol under the assumption that it would normally only be the class' name which caused the class to be retained by the GC, but installing a SBCL finalization function on that class and then setting the symbol value of TEST to NIL shows that the class is never GC'd, no matter how many times I run `(gc :full t)`. Which leaves me wondering if it's possible, and if so, how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not matter that the class name, a symbol, is not interned in a package. `FIND-CLASS` will find the class by looking at some internal registry data structure. Clozure Common Lisp uses for example a normal hash table `CCL::%FIND-CLASSES%`.

There is no standard way. The Common Lisp standard provides no mechanism. Typically a CLOS implementation will want to provide a list of all subclasses of a certain class. For that it needs a reference from a class to its subclasses. It is not specified that this should be a *weak* reference. For example CLISP implements it as a *weak* references, other Common Lisp implementations may not.

**Sketch of a solution**:

- So in a finalizer you would need calls to `REMOVE-DIRECT-SUBCLASS` (in what package that function may be, often in package `CLOS`) to remove the class from its superclasses.
- You also need to call `(setf (find-class 'my-class-to-be-removed) nil)`.
- You also better look that the class does not have subclasses itself.

So you may be able to build something using the widely supported MOP and implementation specific finalizers.

Comment: You certainly seem to be right that there's no standard way. I just tried even just instancing a class with `(make-instance 'standard-class ...)`, but I can't even get that to be GC'd even though I've manually hacked away every reference to it that I've been able to find (including those you've listed). It's a pity.

Comment: @Dolda2000: I would ask the specific mailing lists - where the implementors answer questions. They should be able to provide more help.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that by now. I was just hoping there'd be a way to do it in standard CLOS. :)